# Как правильно сделать Redirect OpenCart?

Tags: редирект, .htaccess

Был старый двигатель со структурой /index.php?productID=7305&discuss=yes, мне нужно сделать редирект на главную страницу нового сайта, но так чтобы выдавался код 404.

Answer (score 1):

По логике для этого делается это совершенно не так.
Делается специальная маска и указывается код не 404, а другой (не помню какой) о том что страница была перемещена и редирект на соответствующую страницу.
Если же вы хотите делать то что написали, то достаточно написать кастомную 404 страницу с Redirect и возвращающую 404. О том как это сделать можете ознакомится на сайте [php.ru](http://php.ru), там есть подробная документация на русском языке по этому языку программирования. Если вы используете не php ищите документацию к своему языку программирования.
Если я вас не правильно понял, пожалуйста перепишите свой вопрос в более понятной форме.